# Loopback authorize a user to see only their data

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs

I am developing a NodeJS application using Loopback.

I am pretty new to both nodejs and REST APIs, so please correct me if I am conceptually wrong.

Loopback automatically builds CRUD REST APIs, which is a feature I would like to use in order to avoid to write APIs by myself, but I need to limit users to be able to see only their data.

For example, imagine there are 3 tables in my DB, `user`, `book` and a relation table `user_book`.

So for example:

```
table user
    id | name
    ---------
    1 | user1
    2 | user2
    3 | user3

table book
    id | title | author
    -------------------
    1 | title1 | author1
    2 | title2 | author1
    3 | title3 | author2
    4 | title4 | author2
    5 | title5 | author3

table user_book
    id | user_id | book_id
    -------------------
    1 |     1    |    1
    2 |     1    |    4
    3 |     1    |    3
    4 |     2    |    3
    5 |     2    |    2
    6 |     2    |    1
    7 |     3    |    3
```

When a user `X` is authenticated, the API `/books` should answer with ONLY X's books, and not every book in the table. For example, if user `user1` is logged and calls `/books`, they should only get their books, so books with id `1, 3, 4`.

Similarly, `/books?filter[where][book_author]='author1'` should return only books of user `X` whose author is 'author1'.

I found out that loopback offers [remote hooks](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Remote-hooks.html#overview) to attach before and after the execution of a remote method, and also offers so called [scopes](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#scopes) to

> [...]specify commonly-used queries that you can reference as method calls
> on a model[...]

I was thinking about using a combination of the 2 in order to limit access to the table `books` to only rows of the user that runs calls the API.

```
module.exports = function (book) {

  // before every operation on table book
  book.beforeRemote('**', function (ctx, user, next) {
    [HERE I WOULD PERFORM A QUERY TO FIND THE BOOKS ASSOCIATED WITH THE USER, LET'S CALL ID book_list]

    ctx._ds = book.defaultScope; // save the default scope
    book.defaultScope = function () {
      return {
        'where': {
          id in book_list
        }
      };
    };

    next();
  });

  book.afterRemote('**', function (ctx, user, next) {
    book.defaultScope = ctx._ds; // restore the default scope
    next();
  });
};
```

Would this solution work? In particular, I am particularly concerned about concurrency. If multiple requests happen for `/books` from different users, would changing the default scope be a critical operation?

Answer (score 5):

The way we accomplished this was to create a mixin.  Have a look at the loopback timestamp mixin in github.  I would recommend the mixin create an "owner" relation to your user model.  Here's how it works in a nutshell:

- Each model that uses the mixin will have a relation created between the model and the user
- Every time a new instance of the model is created, the userId will be saved with the instance
- Everytime *find* or *findById* is called, the query will be amended to add the **{where:{userId:[currently logged in user id]}}** clause

**/common/mixins/owner.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(Model, options) {
  // get the user model
  var User = Model.getDataSource().models.User;
  // create relation to the User model and call it owner
  Model.belongsTo(User, {as: 'owner', foreignKey: 'ownerId'});

  // each time your model instance is saved, make sure the current user is set as the owner
  // need to do this for upsers too (code not here)
  Model.observe('before save', (ctx, next)=>{
    var instanceOrData = ctx.data ? 'data' : 'instance';
    ctx[instanceOrData].ownerId = ctx.options.accessToken.userId;
  });

  // each time your model is accessed, add a where-clause to filter by the current user
  Model.observe('access', (ctx, next)=>{
    const userId = safeGet(ctx, 'options.accessToken.userId');
    if (!userId) return next();  // no access token, internal or test request;
    var userIdClause = {userId: userId};

    // this part is tricky because you may need to add
    // the userId filter to an existing where-clause

    ctx.query = ctx.query || {};
    if (ctx.query.where) {
      if (ctx.query.where.and) {
        if (!ctx.query.where.and.some((andClause)=>{
          return andClause.hasOwnProperty('userId');
        })) {
          ctx.query.where.and.push(userIdClause);
        }
      } else {
        if (!ctx.query.where.userId) {
          var tmpWhere = ctx.query.where;
          ctx.query.where = {};
          ctx.query.where.and = [tmpWhere, userIdClause];
        }
      }
    } else {
      ctx.query.where = userIdClause;
    }
    next();
  });
};
```

**/common/models/book.json**

```
{
  "mixins": {
    "Owner": true
  }
}
```

Every time you use the Owner mixin, that model will automatically have a ownerId property added and filled each time a new instance is created or saved and the results will automatically be filtered each time you "get" the data.

Comment: Your solution is super elegant!

Comment: Your model.observe fuction seems to be missing a next() statement. At least it was in my case. Otherwise great solution!

Comment: It sure is!  Good catch.

Comment: @YeeHaw1234 This does not look secure. The API caller can specify any userId filter they want, allowing them to access other user's data. This code doesn't add the new filter if there is already one in place. (Also, it doesn't search the whole filter tree for nested and clauses.) Try this instead `ctx.query.where = ctx.query.where ? {and: [userIdClause, ctx.query.where]} : userIdClause;`

Comment: @MikeFisher I'm adding the userId clause in the outermost and clause so I think it will handle any nested or clause:  `false AND (false OR true)`, so even if a user slips in a "where userId === myId", the outsermost AND would be applied and ignore any inner clauses that try to bypass the security

Comment: @YeeHaw1234 I'm not seeing that in the code. If there is a where with top-level and condition, the code `if (!ctx.query.where.and.some((andClause)...` won't add the new condition if an existing userId condition is found. And if there is a where with a different top-level condition, the code `if (!ctx.query.where.userId)...` won't add the new condition if the top-level condition is a userId condition.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is using loopback relation. You must set the relation:
- User has many book through user book
- Book has many user through user book

It is similar to this example provided by loopback documentation: [loopback docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/HasManyThrough-relations.html)

So let's say user should be **authenticated before using the function**, then you can pass user/**userId**/books to get books accessible by specific user.

If you want to limit the access, then you should use ACL. For this case, you must use custom role resolver, the same example is provided by loopback: [roleResolver](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html)

If you applied this resolver, then user can only access the books that belongs to them.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to your problem:

**/common/models/user_book.json**

```
{
  "name": "user_book",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "user_id": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "book_id": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "user",
      "foreignKey": "user_id"
    },
    "book": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "book",
      "foreignKey": "book_id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [{
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "*"
    }],
  "methods": []
}
```

**/common/models/book**

```
{
  "name": "book",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "author": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
      "users": {
        "type": "hasMany",
        "model": "user",
        "foreignKey": "book_id",
        "through": "user_book"
      }
  },
  "acls": [{
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "*"
    }],
  "methods": []
}
```

**/common/models/user.json**

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "projects": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "project",
      "foreignKey": "ownerId"
    },
    "teams": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "team",
      "foreignKey": "ownerId"
    },
    "books": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "book",
      "foreignKey": "user_id",
      "through": "user_book"
    }
  },
  "acls": [{
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "listMyBooks"
    }],
  "methods": []
}
```

Then in the user model js file, you need to create a customized remote method with HTTP verb "GET" and has route "/books". In its handling function, you should obtain the authenticated user instance (with the access token information) and just return user.books (implemented by loopback for the through relation) to obtain its related books specified by the user_book model. Here is the code example:

**/common/models/user.js**

```
module.exports = function(User) {
  User.listMyBooks = function(accessToken,cb) {
    User.findOne({where:{id:accessToken.userId}},function(err,user) {
      user.books(function (err,books){
          if (err) return cb(err);
          return cb(null,books);
      });
    });
  };
  User.remoteMethod('listMyBooks', {
    accepts: [{arg: 'accessToken', type: 'object', http: function(req){return req.res.req.accessToken}}],
    returns: {arg: 'books', type: 'array'},
    http: {path:'/books', verb: 'get'}
  });
};
```

Please also make sure the remote methods are exposed for public access:

**/server/model-config.json:**

```
  ...
  "user": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
  "book": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
  "user_book": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  }
  ...
```

With these, you should be able to call `GET /users/books?access_token=[authenticated token obtained from POST /users/login]` 
to obtain the list of books belonging to the authenticated user.
See references for the use of has-many-through relation in loopback: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/HasManyThrough-relations.html

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to YeeHaw1234's answer. I plan to use Mixins the way he describes, but I needed more fields than just User ID to filter the data. I have 3 other fields that I wanted to add to the Access token so I could enforce data rules at the lowest possible level.

I wanted to add some fields to the session, but couldn't figure out how in Loopback. I looked at express-session and cookie-express, but the problem was that I did not want to rewrite the Loopback login and Login seemed like the place where the session fields should be set.

My solution was to create a Custom User and Custom Access Token and add the fields I needed. I then used an operation hook (before save) to insert my new fields before a new Access Token was written.

Now every time someone logs in, I get my extra fields. Feel free to let me know if there is an easier way to add fields to a session. I plan to add an update Access Token so that if the user's permissions change while they are logged in that they will see those changes in the session.

Here is some of the code.

/common/models/mr-access-token.js

```
var app = require('../../server/server');

module.exports = function(MrAccessToken) {

  MrAccessToken.observe('before save', function addUserData(ctx, next) {
    const MrUser = app.models.MrUser;
    if (ctx.instance) {
      MrUser.findById(ctx.instance.userId)
        .then(result => {
        ctx.instance.setAttribute("role");
        ctx.instance.setAttribute("teamId");
        ctx.instance.setAttribute("leagueId");
        ctx.instance.setAttribute("schoolId");
        ctx.instance.role = result.role;
        ctx.instance.teamId = result.teamId;
        ctx.instance.leagueId = result.leagueId;
        ctx.instance.schoolId = result.schoolId;
        next();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Yikes!');
      })
    } else {
      MrUser.findById(ctx.instance.userId)
        .then(result => {
        ctx.data.setAttribute("role");
        ctx.data.setAttribute("teamId");
        ctx.data.setAttribute("leagueId");
        ctx.data.setAttribute("schoolId");
        ctx.data.role = result.role;
        ctx.data.teamId = result.teamId;
        ctx.data.leagueId = result.leagueId;
        ctx.data.schoolId = result.schoolId;
        next();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Yikes!');
      })
    }
  })


};
```

This took me a long time to debug. Here was a few hurdles I had. I initially thought it needed to be in /server/boot, but I wasn't seeing the code triggered on saves. When I moved it to /common/models it started firing. Trying to figure out how to reference a 2nd model from within the observer wasn't in the docs. The `var app = ...` was in another SO answer. The last big problem was I had the `next()` outside the async findById so the instance was being returned unchanged and then the async code would modify the value.

/common/models/mr-user.js

```
{
  "name": "MrUser",
  "base": "User",
  "options": {
    "idInjection": false,
    "mysql": {
      "schema": "matrally",
      "table": "MrUser"
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "role": {
      "type": "String",
      "enum": ["TEAM-OWNER",
        "TEAM-ADMIN",
        "TEAM-MEMBER",
        "SCHOOL-OWNER",
        "SCHOOL-ADMIN",
        "SCHOOL-MEMBER",
        "LEAGUE-OWNER",
        "LEAGUE-ADMIN",
        "LEAGUE-MEMBER",
        "NONE"],
      "default": "NONE"
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "accessTokens": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "MrAccessToken",
      "foreignKey": "userId",
      "options": {
        "disableInclude": true
      }
    },
    "league": {
      "model": "League",
      "type": "belongsTo"
    },
    "school": {
      "model": "School",
      "type": "belongsTo"
    },
    "team": {
      "model": "Team",
      "type": "belongsTo"
    }
  }
}
```

/common/models/mr-user.js

```
{
  "name": "MrAccessToken",
  "base": "AccessToken",
  "options": {
    "idInjection": false,
    "mysql": {
      "schema": "matrally",
      "table": "MrAccessToken"
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "role": {
      "type": "String"
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "mrUser": {
      "model": "MrUser",
      "type": "belongsTo"
    },
    "league": {
      "model": "League",
      "type": "belongsTo"
    },
    "school": {
      "model": "School",
      "type": "belongsTo"
    },
    "team": {
      "model": "Team",
      "type": "belongsTo"
    }
  }
}
```

/server/boot/mrUserRemoteMethods.js

```
var senderAddress = "curtis@abcxyz.com"; //Replace this address with your actual address
var config = require('../../server/config.json');
var path = require('path');


module.exports = function(app) {
  const MrUser = app.models.MrUser;


  //send verification email after registration
  MrUser.afterRemote('create', function(context, user, next) {
    var options = {
      type: 'email',
      to: user.email,
      from: senderAddress,
      subject: 'Thanks for registering.',
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../server/views/verify.ejs'),
      redirect: '/verified',
      user: user
    };

    user.verify(options, function(err, response) {
      if (err) {
        MrUser.deleteById(user.id);
        return next(err);
      }
      context.res.render('response', {
        title: 'Signed up successfully',
        content: 'Please check your email and click on the verification link ' +
            'before logging in.',
        redirectTo: '/',
        redirectToLinkText: 'Log in'
      });
    });
  });

  // Method to render
  MrUser.afterRemote('prototype.verify', function(context, user, next) {
    context.res.render('response', {
      title: 'A Link to reverify your identity has been sent '+
        'to your email successfully',
      content: 'Please check your email and click on the verification link '+
        'before logging in',
      redirectTo: '/',
      redirectToLinkText: 'Log in'
    });
  });

  //send password reset link when requested
  MrUser.on('resetPasswordRequest', function(info) {
    var url = 'http://' + config.host + ':' + config.port + '/reset-password';
    var html = 'Click <a href="' + url + '?access_token=' +
        info.accessToken.id + '">here</a> to reset your password';

    MrUser.app.models.Email.send({
      to: info.email,
      from: senderAddress,
      subject: 'Password reset',
      html: html
    }, function(err) {
      if (err) return console.log('> error sending password reset email');
      console.log('> sending password reset email to:', info.email);
    });
  });

  //render UI page after password change
  MrUser.afterRemote('changePassword', function(context, user, next) {
    context.res.render('response', {
      title: 'Password changed successfully',
      content: 'Please login again with new password',
      redirectTo: '/',
      redirectToLinkText: 'Log in'
    });
  });

  //render UI page after password reset
  MrUser.afterRemote('setPassword', function(context, user, next) {
    context.res.render('response', {
      title: 'Password reset success',
      content: 'Your password has been reset successfully',
      redirectTo: '/',
      redirectToLinkText: 'Log in'
    });
  });

};
```

This is straight from the examples, but it wasn't clear that it should be registered in /boot. I couldn't get my custom user to send emails until I moved it from /common/models to /server/boot.

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(Model, options) {
  // get the user model
  var User = Model.getDataSource().models.User;
  var safeGet = require("l-safeget");
  // create relation to the User model and call it owner
  Model.belongsTo(User, {as: 'owner', foreignKey: 'ownerId'});

  // each time your model instance is saved, make sure the current user is set as the owner
  // need to do this for upsers too (code not here)
  Model.observe('before save', (ctx, next)=>{
    var instanceOrData = ctx.data ? 'data' : 'instance';
    ctx[instanceOrData].ownerId = ctx.options.accessToken.userId;
    next();
  });

Model.observe('access', (ctx, next)=>{
    const userId = safeGet(ctx, 'options.accessToken.userId');
    if (!userId) return next();  // no access token, internal or test request;
    var userIdClause = {ownerId: userId};

    // this part is tricky because you may need to add
    // the userId filter to an existing where-clause

    ctx.query = ctx.query || {};
    if (ctx.query.where) {
        if (!ctx.query.where.ownerId) {
          var tmpWhere = ctx.query.where;
          ctx.query.where = {};
          ctx.query.where.and = [tmpWhere, userIdClause];

  }     }
     else {
      ctx.query.where = userIdClause;

    }
    next();
 });
};
```

Use this mixim instead of @YeeHaw1234 answer . All other steps are same.

Comment: What is l-safeget? I did some searching and didn't come up with any project or library. Thx

Comment: I found it. Not sure why I didn't know you could search at npmjs.com

Comment: This does not look secure. The API caller can specify any ownerId filter they want, allowing them to access other user's data. This code doesn't add the new filter if there is already one in place.